# How to fix strange rendering behaviour of OSM Data in Mapnik?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

My current setup so far is a running Apache webserver with tilecache.cgi script and a mapnik rendering engine connecting to my postgis database containing my OSM data.

The problem is very easy to describe. All roadnames, roadnumbers, descriptions are to close to each other. I set up tilecache with MetaTile=true, TileSize=8x8 and it doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image: Screeny]

Comment: Can you make use of the TextSymbolizer? https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/TextSymbolizer

Comment: How did you import your data? I am asking because the streets looks like they've been split at intersections - this is not the standard for OSM data.

Comment: with osm2pgsql - Can you show me your command line? I might have choosen wrong params...

Comment: osm2pgsql should be fine and the command line arguments won't change how the data is imported.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the name for "Rue de l'Abbe Bovet" (you're most likely rendering the OSM data from [here](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=46.804464&lon=7.154567&zoom=18&layers=M)) is appearing twice, I don't think there's a problem with the data (it's a single object in OSM, see [here](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/128416935) but rather the renderer (mapnik/tilecache).

As suggested in the comments (by Michael Markieta) check your TextSymbolizer definitions. The relevant attribute is called `spacing` E.g.:

```
<Rule>
<Filter>[highway] = 'tertiary'</Filter>
  &maxscale_zoom17;
  &minscale_zoom18;
  <TextSymbolizer name="name" ... placement="line" spacing="500"/>
</Rule>
```

would cause tertiary road labels to be repeated every 500 pixels.

Another thing that may be worth tinkering with is mapnik's parameter called `buffer_size`. I'm not sure how this works in tilecache (I've only used it in the python mapnik extensions).

**As far as I remember what `buffer_size` does is**: whenever mapnik renders something it looks at whatever is rendered through a window of `buffer_size` - if you want mapnik to realize it has to avoid painting a label because it's already there the label candidate and the already painted label have to coexist within the same rendering window.